# VMware with Power shell

Tags: powershell, vmware

I want to know the host IP of a given VM when we give VM's IP on the script.
Suppose we have a vm ip `10.67.154.30` now i want to find the host ip on which this vm is running.

Comment: Superuser is not a script writing service. What have you tried so far? Do you have PowerCLI installed. If so you could get the name of the VM from the IP, then get the name of the host fro that VM from PowerCLI, then get the IP for that host.

Comment: Get-VMHost -VM Lab_Test   With this command i can get VM Host ip of this vm Lab_Test. Now i want that when we provide ip of this vm i can get VM Host ip.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want then I think this function should do what you want (or at least point you in the right direction):

```
function Find-VMHostIP{
    param(
        $VMName
    )
    $VMHost = Get-VMHost -VM $VMName
    $connectionTest = Test-Connection $VMHost.Name -Count 1
    $hostIP = $connectionTest.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString
    $hostIP
}
```

That is just the bare bones you probably want to put some error handling in there.